# how to select not in relation data using left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I know it's ambiguous subject, because if i know what exactly the name, google will give me the answer. And, sorry for the english.

Okay i have 3 tables looks like below

```
job   job_hide  user  
---   --------  ----  
id    job_id    id  
name  user_id   name
```

let say we have 3 job with 1, 2, 3 as id and 2 user test1, test2 as id and 1 record for job_hide with 2 as job_id and test2 as user_id.

my question is, how i can use left join in case user test2 logged and i want to select all job except job with id 2 because job with id 2 has been added to job_hide table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an is null condition for that purpose:

```
select job.* from job left join job_hide 
on (job.id = job_hide.job_id and job_hide.user_id = 'test2')
where job_hide.job_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name
FROM job
WHERE id NOT IN
      ( SELECT job_id
        FROM job_hide AS jh
        WHERE jh.job_id = job.id
          AND jh.user_id = 2            --- 2 is the @id_of_the_logged_user
       )
```